# Select options without value attribute

Tags: jquery

Is this correct or invalid markup (when the option has no value)?
Is this the expected jQuery behaviour for `.val()` when there is no `value=""` assigned?

```
<select id="select_ID">
    <option></option>
    <option>Name</option>
    <option>Recent</option>
</select>
```

If I use `$("#select_ID").val();` I get "Name"/"Recent", but if the option had a value, I would get the value's content.

I know there is `.text()` to get "Name" and "Recent" in this example. Just confused why does `.val()` gives me the `.text()` when there is no value assigned.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jDw8N/) (notice the different result of the alerts)

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4924

Comment: This is intended to avoid redundancy - HTML forms support this by default as well.

Comment: If there's no `value` for an option, the text between the `<option>` opening and closing tags is what's submitted with the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery. That's how the browser handles it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jDw8N/1/

```
$("#select_ID").change(function () {
    var val = $("#select_ID option:selected")[0].value;
    alert(val); // somevalue or Recent
});
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-value

> The `value` attribute provides a value for element. The **value** of an `option` element is the value of the `value` content attribute, if there is one, or, if there is not, the value of the element's `text` IDL attribute.

Comment: Ok, so the markup is valid and not having a "value" attribute makes text the default value. Thank you for fast answer and explanation.

Answer (score 12):

This is the correct DOM behavior.
You can see this from the [MDN documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option):

> **value**
>
> The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. **If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element**.

Comment: Thank you! +1 to your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure to get the value of `value` attribute you can use following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/sepehrmm/dpmr9h4o/

```
$("#select_ID").change(function () {
    var val = $("option:selected", this).attr('value');
    if(val != undefined){
        alert(val); // this only alerts if the option has a value attribute
    }
});
```